# Reduce Number of Measurements in Calibration

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, feature-selection, supervised-learning

For calibration purposes I am making N measurements of water flow, each of which is time-intensive.  I want to reduce the number of measurements.  It sounds like this is part of feature selection as I am reducing the number of columns I have.  BUT - I need to predict the measurements I will be dropping.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
    SerialNumber  val      speed
0   193604048   1.350254    105.0
1   193604048   1.507517    3125.0
2   193604048   1.455142    525.0
6   193604048   1.211184    12.8
7   193604048   1.238835    20.0
```

For each serial number I have a complete set of speed-val measurements. Ideally I would like a model whose output is the vector of all N val measurements, but it seems the options are all neural networks, which I am trying to avoid for now.  Are there are any other options?

If I feed this data into a regression model, how do I differentiate between each serialNumber dataset?

To make sure my goal is clear - I want to learn the historical measurements I have of N measurements and find which speed-val I can drop to still accurately predict all N output values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find the simplest equation that would give a good fit to the example data you posted, and from my equation search the Harris Yield Density equation, "y = 1.0 / (a + b * pow(x, c))", is an good candidate. Here is a graphical Python fitter using that equation and your data, with initial parameter estimates for the non-linear fitter calculated directly from the data max and min values. Note that SerialNumber itself is unrelated to the data and would not be used in regressions.

My hope is that you might find this equation generally useful in your work, and it might be possible that after performing similar regressions on several different data sets that parameters a, b, and c are very similar in all cases - that is the best outcome. If your measurement accuracy is high, I personally would expect that with this three-parameter equation it should be possible to use a minimum of four data points per calibration, with max, min and two other well-spaced points along the expected calibration curve.

Note that here the fitted parameters a = -1.91719091e-03. b = 1.11357103e+00, and c = -1.51294798e+01 yield RMSE = 3.191 and R-squared = 0.9999

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xData = numpy.array([1.350254, 1.507517, 1.455142, 1.211184, 1.238835])
yData = numpy.array([105.0, 3125.0, 525.0, 12.8, 20.0])


def func(x, a, b, c): # Harris yield density equation
    return 1.0 / (a + b*numpy.power(x, c))


initialParameters = numpy.array([0.0, min(xData), -10.0 * max(xData)])

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_title('Harris Yield Density Equation') # title
    axes.set_xlabel('Val') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Speed') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

UPDATE using reversed X and Y

Per the comments, here is a three-parameter equation Mixed Power and Eponential "a * pow(x, b) * exp(c * x)" graphical fitter with X and Y reversed from the previous code. Here the fitted parameters a = 1.05910664e+00, b = 5.26304345e-02, and -2.25604946e-05 yield RMSE = 0.0003602 and R-squared= 0.9999

[image: plot2]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xData = numpy.array([105.0, 3125.0, 525.0, 12.8, 20.0])
yData = numpy.array([1.350254, 1.507517, 1.455142, 1.211184, 1.238835])


def func(x, a, b, c): # mixed power and exponential equation
    return a * numpy.power(x, b) * numpy.exp(c * x)


initialParameters = [1.0, 0.01, -0.01]

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_title('Mixed Power and Exponential Equation') # title
    axes.set_xlabel('Speed') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Val') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!  I tried this and got an error: RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800.

Also, I may have been unclear - your xData is really yData, and y is x.  Which leads to a more logarithmic, rather than power function.  
Re serialNumber - I know it's just an identifier, but I do want to be able to tell them apart.  Optimally, I will have a function/model based on 4-5 points, as you suggested, and using the fit/model I can predict the other 9-10 points accurately

Comment: Please see the UPDATE section of the answer for the reversed X and Y fitter.

Comment: Apologies for the late response.  Thank you so much!!